# Declare, Set, and Use Variable in SQL Query (not a stored proc)

Tags: sql, sql-server

Maybe I'm missing something simple, but is there a way to declare a variable and use it within a single SQL query?  That way, if you have a piece of information that is generated using a large nested query, you don't have to keep running that same query over and over again.

This would be a decent example illustrating the problem:

```
SELECT id, CASE WHEN LEN(HUGESUBQUERY) > 10 THEN
    LEFT(HUGESUBQUERY, LEN(HUGESUBQUERY)-2) ELSE HUGESUBQUERY END AS result FROM table
```

With everything added in, it gets really long.  Here is the actual query I am working with.  (of note, I am running this from Dynamics AX, so I have no flexibility on doing anything other than everything in one SELECT statement.  None of the solutions with DECLARE, SET, etc. are available in this environment.)

```
SELECT (CAST (
CASE WHEN
RIGHT(
(CONCAT(COALESCE((SELECT TOP 1 SalesId FROM CustInvoiceJour WHERE     
CustInvoiceJour.InvoiceId = T1.INVOICE), 'NONE'), 
'-', ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY T1.ACCOUNTNUM, (SELECT TOP 1 SalesId     
FROM CustInvoiceJour 
WHERE CustInvoiceJour.InvoiceId = T1.INVOICE) ORDER BY T1.DUEDATE)-1))
, 2) = '-0'
THEN
LEFT(
(CONCAT(COALESCE((SELECT TOP 1 SalesId FROM CustInvoiceJour WHERE     
CustInvoiceJour.InvoiceId = T1.INVOICE), 'NONE'), 
'-', ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY T1.ACCOUNTNUM, (SELECT TOP 1 SalesId     
FROM CustInvoiceJour 
WHERE CustInvoiceJour.InvoiceId = T1.INVOICE) ORDER BY T1.DUEDATE)-1)),
LEN(
(CONCAT(COALESCE((SELECT TOP 1 SalesId FROM CustInvoiceJour WHERE     
CustInvoiceJour.InvoiceId = T1.INVOICE), 'NONE'), 
'-', ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY T1.ACCOUNTNUM, (SELECT TOP 1 SalesId     
FROM CustInvoiceJour 
WHERE CustInvoiceJour.InvoiceId = T1.INVOICE) ORDER BY T1.DUEDATE)-1))
)-2
)
ELSE
(CONCAT(COALESCE((SELECT TOP 1 SalesId FROM CustInvoiceJour WHERE 
CustInvoiceJour.InvoiceId = T1.INVOICE), 'NONE'), 
'-', ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY T1.ACCOUNTNUM, (SELECT TOP 1 SalesId     
FROM CustInvoiceJour 
WHERE CustInvoiceJour.InvoiceId = T1.INVOICE) ORDER BY T1.DUEDATE)-1))
END
AS NVARCHAR(21))) AS DOC_ID,
T1.ACCOUNTNUM AS CUSTOMER_ID,T1.AMOUNTCUR AS DOCTOTAL,T1.DUEDATE AS 
DUEDATE,T1.DOCUMENTDATE AS DOCDATE,
T1.RECID AS ID,T1.DATAAREAID AS DATAAREAID,T1.PARTITION AS 
PARTITION,T1.RECID AS RECID,
(CAST ((T1.RECID + T1.RECVERSION) AS BIGINT)) AS SWX_COMPUTEDVERSION FROM     
CUSTTRANS T1 WHERE (AMOUNTCUR>0)
ORDER BY DOC_ID
```

Comment: `DECLARE @s VARCHAR(32); SELECT TOP 1 @s = something FROM somewhere ...; SELECT id, CASE WHEN LEN(@s) ...`

Comment: did you try using CTE?

Comment: @user2169261 If the output of the query is a constant, a CTE won't resolve the issue - it will still be executed multiple times.

Comment: Also, `CASE HUGESUBQUERY WHEN LEN(HUGESUBQUERY) > 10 THEN ...` is a confused mish-mash of the two different forms of `CASE` expression.

Comment: better OP use sqlfiddle

Comment: Or at least show us something real. Don't dumb things down.

Comment: Actual query added.  Fixed syntax on the CASE statement.  Thanks for the responses.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can considering that the `query` is not **Correlated**. Try this

```
DECLARE @HUGESUBQUERY VARCHAR(500) 

SET @HUGESUBQUERY = (SELECT TOP 1 something 
                     FROM   somewhere 
                            INNER JOIN table2 
                                    ON table2.id = somwhere.id 
                            INNER JOIN table3 
                                    ON table3.id = table2.id 
                     WHERE  condition1 = condition1 
                            AND condition2 = condition2) 

SELECT id, 
       CASE @HUGESUBQUERY 
         WHEN Len(@HUGESUBQUERY) > 10 THEN LEFT(@HUGESUBQUERY, 
                                           Len(@HUGESUBQUERY) - 2) 
       END AS result 
FROM   table
```

Comment: That presumes that `HUGHSUBQUERY` isn't a correlated subquery.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever - I don't think the `sub-query` is correlated. Alteast in the given example

Comment: `condition1` or `condition2` could *easily* be referencing columns in outer tables. It's impossible to tell because it's too abstracted from the real problem.

Answer (score 1):

For a correlated subquery, you can use `CROSS APPLY`. Since we don't have a real query, I'll just put one that demonstrates the technique:

```
select
    *,cname
from
    sys.objects so
        cross apply
    (select top 1 sc.name from sys.columns sc where sc.object_id = so.object_id) t (cname)
```

And now `cname` can be used throughout the `SELECT` clause to refer to the `name` value returned from `sys.columns`.